# How to store data for through table related to one of the joining tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the example from the rails tutorial with Physician and Patient, then joining them with the Appointment table..

If the Physician has_many Questions, what is the best way to store the unique answers from the Patients?

Possible solution:
Patient has_many Surveys and Survey has_many Answers.  Create this when a new Appointment is made.
Problem:
I'm finding the views and controllers to be quite complex for something as simple as, to restate my question, store data related to a joining table.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more context as to what you need and the problems you're having with the attempted approach.  Seems like a simple enough concept: Answer belongs to Question and Patient (and Survey and Doctor, extent of denormalization up to you).

Answer (score 4):

At the bottom of all this, it seems to me that you have an Answer - to a Question, during an Appointment, from a Patient, to a Physician.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :physician
```

end

So we also need Question, Appointment, Patient, Physician models, which all "have many" Answers.

Questions can belong to individual Physicians (although I'd think that many Physicians ask the same Questions).

When you create an appointment, you know the Physician, and Patient. Write the Appointment, then fetch the Physician's Questions and create Answer records for each of the Physician's Questions (now you know the IDs of all four related entities). Do this in your Appointment model, not in the controller. Look into ActiveRecord::Callbacks, after_create may be your friend in this case.

Querying becomes very easy in this case, and record IDs (foreign keys) are relatively cheap to store.

Interesting scenario.

Comment: You only need the `:question` and `:appointment` associations. The other relationships can be inferred from `:appointment`.

Comment: @Avilyn - agreed, you can infer the other relationships. When I think about querying data in general, required joins can sometimes degrade performance.

Comment: @railsdog I'd argue that in this instance a query for physician and their patients would not involve a large data set.  I'd argue that using callbacks would make solving bugs more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Physicians don't share questions the following models describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Models (denormalized):

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  has_many :questions
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :answers
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end

class Questions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  has_one    :answer
end

class Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

**Edit** Regarding querying (its not as difficult as you would expect)

Getting all patients for a physician:

`Physician.find(1).patients`

Getting all questions for a physician:

`Physician.find(1).questions`

Getting all answers for a patient:

`Patient.find(1).answers`